# Django inlineformset_factory doesn't delete records

Tags: django, django-forms

Here is my code:

```
PartFormSet = inlineformset_factory(ReservationPaper, ReservationPaperPart,
                                    ReservationPaperPartEditForm, extra=0)
if request.method == "POST":
    try:
        part_formset = PartFormSet(data=request.POST, instance=rp)
    except:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(request.path_info)
    rp_form = ReservationPaperForm(instance=rp, data=request.POST)

    if part_formset.is_valid() and rp_form.is_valid():
        rp_form.save()
        for part_form in part_formset.forms:
            part_form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("internal:documents:display_reservation_paper",
                                        args=[rp.id]))
else:
    rp_form = ReservationPaperForm(instance=rp)
    part_formset = PartFormSet(instance=rp)
```

It renders delete checkboxes for each part_formset instance, however, when I submit the forms entries are only edited, not deleted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't doing anything special when you save the formset, so you can just call `part_formset.save()` instead of iterating through the forms individually.